# ajax adding information to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, activerecord

im still fairly new to the whole ruby on rails stuff, though i have read that you can easily perform ajax requests. what im trying to do is add a new row to the database table, and pass a few variables from it.

what i have at present is

```
%li= link_to image_tag('trans.gif', :border => 0, :size => '16x16', :class => 'i-16-tick'), availabilities_path(:team_id => schedule.team_id, :user_id => current_user, :schedule_id => schedule.id), :remote => true, :method => :post, :title => 'Accept', :rel => 'tooltip-html'
```

controller code

`# POST /availabilities
  # POST /availabilities.json
  def create
    @availability = Availability.new(params[:availability])

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @availability.save
    format.html { redirect_to @availability, :notice => 'Availability was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :json => @availability, :status => :created, :location => @availability }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.json { render :json => @availability.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end
`

though how does it know what variables to pass to the database?

this is what is happening at present

`Processing by AvailabilitiesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"schedule_id"=>"18", "team_id"=>"1", "user_id"=>"38"}
  User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 38 LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (20.1ms)  INSERT INTO "availabilities" ("available", "created_at", "schedule_id", "team_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["available", nil], ["created_at", Tue, 18 Sep 2012 23:07:26 EST +10:00], ["schedule_id", nil], ["team_id", nil], ["updated_at", Tue, 18 Sep 2012 23:07:26 EST +10:00], ["user_id", nil]]
   (10.5ms)  COMMIT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass more than one variable to the server you include them in the http request. This is true for AJAX requests as well as regular ones. For example:

```
<%= link_to 'Send data', accept_availabilty( player, :my_variable => value1, :my_variable => value2), :remote => true %>
```

Often though with more complex submissions you'll want to use a remote form rather than just a simple link.

Comment: problem im having is that its GETTING and not PUTTING ie ie `Started GET "/availabilities?schedule_id=18&team_id=1&user_id=38" for ****** at 2012-09-18 14:53:05 +0200
Processing by AvailabilitiesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"schedule_id"=>"18", "team_id"=>"1", "user_id"=>"38"}
`

Comment: That's a different issue but you can modify the method of a link by using `:method => :put` or whatever. Check out http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html

Comment: have fixed that issue, but its like my params arent being detected within the controller :S

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're trying to send but you can check what happens either in the server logs (per your example earlier: `{"schedule_id"=>"18", "team_id"=>"1", "user_id"=>"38"} `) or even better check the http request itself with Firebug (you can see the ajax request details in the Console tab.) If those look ok you may have to debug the controller itself, see if you're using the correct parameter keys. If you're PUTing data you might have to use a remote form instead of a remote link too, I'm not 100% sure url-encoded parameters will work with a PUT request.

Comment: this is what i have in my controller, the ajax request is working, its sending the data, just i cant get the controller to detect what params are being sent through

Comment: If you see this `Parameters: {"schedule_id"=>"18", "team_id"=>"1", "user_id"=>"38"}` in your log then certainly those parameters should be available in the controller (as `params[:schedule_id]` etc.) If that's not the case then something is seriously wrong, I wouldn't know what could cause a problem like that to be honest.

Comment: if i call them like that i current have this in place `@availability = Availability.new(params[:availability])` and i have attempted to allocate those params to that instance without luck

Comment: That makes sense, as you can see in the log `{"schedule_id"=>"18", "team_id"=>"1", "user_id"=>"38"}` does not include an `availability` key. Nor do I see any reference to "availability" in your link_to statement. Could you clarify, are these form values you're trying to send? Where is this availability data supposed to come from?

Comment: got it work with the following `%li= link_to image_tag('trans.gif', :border => 0, :size => '16x16', :class => 'i-16-tick'), availabilities_path(:availability => {:team_id => schedule.team_id, :user_id => current_user, :schedule_id => schedule.id}), :remote => true, :method => :post, :title => 'Accept', :rel => 'tooltip-html'
                          `

Comment: not sure if its best way of achieving it but it delivers the desired result

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass information to your rails app, you will need to place the

```
:remote => true
```

on to the form_for tag, then your controller will be able to pass those params on to your model.

Comment: i have the remote true, but say i wanted to pass player_id, schedule_id how does the app pick them up?